# How does a bundle (Sytem.Web.Optimization) generate the build fingerprint for bundle-links?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-optimization

In MVC-4, bundles for compressing CSS & Js files can be linked in a layout file with this Razor syntax: `@Scripts.Render("~/JavaScripts")`

This generates a link in the layout file that includes a [fingerprint](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching), which is re-generated on each app-build, to assist with cache-control.

So the generated link looks like:

```
<script src="/JavaScripts?v=dSMc_JTHMMP5GrWnILSYt_QBMw-g1pPlzknSorXpkyQ1"></script>
```

I'd like to know how the fingerprint is being generated (to use for similar purposes), but Sytem.Web.Optimization is not yet open-source.

Comment: I don't know about System.Web.Optimization, but IIRC SquishIt uses hashes of the file contents to create this fingerprint. You could hash all files involved in the process and use a hash of it if the purpose of your fingerprinting is to change it whenever any content inside a file changes. For reference you can look at SquishIt source -> https://github.com/jetheredge/SquishIt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fingerprint is generated using a sha256 hash of the bytes from the bundle and then encoded:

```
            byte[] hash = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(bundle));
            return HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(hash);
```

Comment: When and where does this happen?  Is there an event I can hook to be able to trigger my own code whenever this happens?